# Successfull call to bind(2) with AF_UNIX does not generate a socket file

Tags: unix-socket

I have a program that should generate a socket. Using strace I get the following trace line

```
bind(6, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/home/me/x"}, 110) = 0
```

However, "/home/me/x" does not exist and I see no call of unlink. May it happen, that no file is created even if the call is successful (=0) ?

Disclaimer: The program in question is https://github.com/nixcloud/ip2unix so it does some nasty stuff by replacing sockets. However, the bind call gives success and the program normally works, so am I missing sth. ? Shouldn't the file in all cases exist now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I think that is not possible. What I did not account for was that `strace` does not follow children, so after a helpful hint `strace -f` showed the unlink call. I guess `inotifywait` would have revealed too that the socket file was actually created before unlinked...